# Junit test для метода, который возвращает объект Path

Tags: java, junit

может быть, кто-то направит в нужное русло.. есть такой класс, задача которого возвращать объект Path (java.nio) для дальнейшего чтения файлов

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class FileLoader {

    public Path loadFile(String name) throws URISyntaxException, FileNotFoundException {
        if (name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("input can't be null");
        }
        URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(name);
        if (url == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException(
                    String.format("file %s was not found or access to the resource is denied", name));
        }
        return Paths.get(url.toURI());
    }
}
```

как мне протестировать метод loadFile в junit

я написал такой тест:

```
 @Test
void loadFileTest_ShouldNotThrowAnyExceptions_WhenFileExist() throws FileNotFoundException, URISyntaxException {
    FileLoader loader = new FileLoader();
    assertDoesNotThrow(() -> loader.loadFile("startTest1.log"));
}
```

но нужно тестировать именно результат (то есть то что возвращает метод, то есть сравнить с чем-то объект Path

Comment: Один из вариантов Jimfs - https://www.baeldung.com/jimfs-file-system-mocking

Comment: ок, спасибо! попробую